# Creating a Sierpinski triangle

Tags: python, recursion, canvas, draw

I'm attempting to create a Sierpinski triangle with the ezgraphics library using recursion. I imagine that there are several things that I have done wrong but I'm stuck as I am relatively new to coding. I'm not looking for someone to complete the code for me, just suggestions as to what to try next.

Here is the library I'm using: http://www.ezgraphics.org/ReferenceGuide/ReferenceGuide

And here is my rough code so far:

```
from ezgraphics import GraphicsWindow

def main():
    winSpec = int(input("enter the size of the window: "))
    subDiv = int(input("Enter number of subdivisions: "))
    win = GraphicsWindow(winSize,winSize)
    canvas = win.canvas()
    canvas.setColor( "blue" )
    triangle1 = [winSpec/2, 0, 0, winSpec, winSpec, winSpec]
    drawGasket(triangle1,subDiv,canvas)
    #canvas.drawPolygon(triangle1[0],triangle1[1],triangle1[2],triangle1[3],triangle1[4],triangle1[5])  
    win.wait()

def drawGasket(points,subDiv,canvas):    
    print(points)
    canvas.drawPolygon(points[0],points[1],points[2],points[3],points[4],points[5])  
    if subDiv > 0:
        print("hi")
        points2 = [points[0] + points[2] /2,points[1] + points[3] /2, points[0] + points[4] /2,points[1] + points[5] /2, points[2] + points[4] /2,points[3] + points[5] /2]
        drawGasket(points2, subDiv - 1, canvas)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you be a little more specific about what you're stuck on? Please walk us through the code a bit and your thought process.

Comment: don't expect that we will run code to see your problem. And code can work correctly on ours computer. You have to descrice what you get and what you want to get. If you get error message then put full error in question (not in comment) as text (not image)

Comment: BTW: shorter `canvas.drawPolygon(points)`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very specific, I don't currently run into any errors when the code runs instead I am stuck on how to make the triangles that are drawn follow the pattern that the Sierpinski triangle is supposed to. For example my program currently draws the 2nd,3rd and so on triangle out side of the bounding box of the canvas instead of where I thought it was going to.  Here is a [picture](https://imgur.com/a/dr1uzMX) for reference with the canvas made much larger in order to fit the out of bounds triangles.

Comment: as I rember `Sierpinski triangle` you should draw triangle only for `subDiv == 0` and for other values you should find three smaller triangles and run `drawGasket` three times with smaller triangels `drawGasket(smaller_triangel1, subDiv - 1, canvas)`, `drawGasket(smaller_triangel2, subDiv - 1, canvas)`, `drawGasket(smaller_triangel3, subDiv - 1, canvas)`

Comment: BTW: to make code more readable you could use `x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = points` and then calculate middle points like `middle1_x = (x2-x1)/2` and later use this `middle1_x` to create new three triangles.

Comment: BTW: you could use `print()` to see calculations for every middle point separatelly. And you should start testing with `subDiv = 0` and next with `subDiv = 1` to see if it works correctly for other values

Comment: BTW: you have to use `()` to first add values and later divide - `(points[0] + points[2]) /2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should draw only for `subDiv == 0` and for other values you should calculate middle points and run again with three new triangles.

You have to use `()` to divide sum - `(points[0] + points[2]) /2`. Without `()` you divide second point before adding points.

---

**BTW**

Shorter

```
 canvas.drawPolygon(points)
```

You can assing points to variables which means something to make code more readable

```
 x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = points
```

and then you can calculate middle points

```
 middle_1_2_x = (x1+x2)/2
 middle_1_2_y = (y1+y2)/2

 middle_2_3_x = (x2+x3)/2
 middle_2_3_y = (y2+y3)/2

 middle_1_3_x = (x1+x3)/2
 middle_1_3_y = (y1+y3)/2
```

before you create new triangles

```
 triangle1 = [x1, y1, middle_1_2_x, middle_1_2_y, middle_1_3_x, middle_1_3_y]
 triangle2 = [middle_1_2_x, middle_1_2_y, x2, y2, middle_2_3_x, middle_2_3_y]
 triangle3 = [middle_1_3_x, middle_1_3_y, middle_2_3_x, middle_2_3_y, x3, y3]
```

---

**Result:**

[image]

---

**Full code:**

```
from ezgraphics import GraphicsWindow

def main():
    #winSpec = int(input("enter the size of the window: "))
    #subDiv = int(input("Enter number of subdivisions: "))

    winSpec = 600
    subDiv = 2

    win = GraphicsWindow(winSpec, winSpec)
    canvas = win.canvas()
    canvas.setColor("blue")

    triangle = [winSpec/2, 0, 0, winSpec, winSpec, winSpec]
    print('start:', triangle)
    drawGasket(triangle, subDiv, canvas)

    win.wait()

def drawGasket(triangle, subDiv, canvas):    
    if subDiv == 0:
        print(' draw:', triangle)
        canvas.drawPolygon(triangle)
    else:
        x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = triangle

        middle_1_2_x = (x1+x2)/2
        middle_1_2_y = (y1+y2)/2
        print('middle 1-2:', middle_1_2_x, middle_1_2_y)

        middle_2_3_x = (x2+x3)/2
        middle_2_3_y = (y2+y3)/2
        print('middle 2-3:', middle_2_3_x, middle_2_3_y)

        middle_1_3_x = (x1+x3)/2
        middle_1_3_y = (y1+y3)/2
        print('middle 1-3:', middle_1_3_x, middle_1_3_y)

        triangle1 = [x1, y1, middle_1_2_x, middle_1_2_y, middle_1_3_x, middle_1_3_y]
        drawGasket(triangle1, subDiv-1, canvas)

        triangle2 = [middle_1_2_x, middle_1_2_y, x2, y2, middle_2_3_x, middle_2_3_y]
        drawGasket(triangle2, subDiv-1, canvas)

        triangle3 = [middle_1_3_x, middle_1_3_y, middle_2_3_x, middle_2_3_y, x3, y3]
        drawGasket(triangle3, subDiv-1, canvas)

main()
```

Comment: Assigning points to variables made it much easier for me to understand. Thank you for being so helpful I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**Not related to the ezgraphics python library**

I ran into this generation method while messing around with an absolute difference function. Note that every number in a list of integers X is simultaneously replaced with the absolute difference of its two neighbors:

```
def absolute_difference(X):
    return [abs(X[(i-1)%len(X)]-X[(i+1)%len(X)]) for i in range(len(X))]
```

I was trying to determine the period of a given starting list, and used the following code to calculate the period, and display each iteration of the function:

```
def period(X, speed):
    Y = [X]
    print(gui(X, speed))
    period = 0
    while True:
        X_n = absolute_difference(Y[-1])
        if X_n in Y:
            print(gui(X_n, speed))
            return period - Y.index(X_n) + 1
        period += 1
        Y.append(X_n)
        print(gui(X_n, speed))

def gui(X_n, sleep_time):
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    output = ""
    for digit in X_n:
        if digit == 1:
            output += "\033[97m██" # text color white
        else:
            output += "\033[30m██" # text color black
    return output
```

If you use the following seed list X where N is equal to a power of 2, it generates a discrete version of the sierpinski triangle represented as 1's and 0's.

```
X = [0] * (N//2 + N%2 - 1) + [1] + [0] * (N//2)
```

Here is the pattern generated for N = 32:

[image: N = 32]

If N is a prime number (N > 7) the resulting patterns that get generated quickly devolve into chaos. Here is a subset of the pattern when N = 37 which has a period length of 87,381:

[image: N = 37]

You can choose to start with any sequence of numbers for X and the period will always be finite since the absolute difference function keeps all numbers in the sequence bounded they must eventually repeat by the pigeon-hole principle. Although this gui function only supports displaying lists containing 1's and 0's.

Let me know what you think of this!